# Android permissions: Phone Calls: read phone state and identity

Tags: android

My android app has nothing to do with phone calls, but I'm seeing that when I install a debug build on my test device it requires "Phone Calls: read phone state and identity" permissions.  (I make no mention of this in `AndroidManifest.xml`).

I'd like to have the minimum possible permissions, and wondered if anyone knew how to get rid of this?  I commented out the part where I was logging some stuff from `Build.MODEL`, `Build.VERSION.*`, etc.  I also commented out the part where I was detecting the landscape/portrait orientation thinking that that might be the "phone state".  But neither of those seemed to remove that permission required.

I found this bug report: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4101  but it's marked working-as-intended with a note about permissions being correct from the market but not otherwise.  Is this other people's experience?  (I'd hate to have to publish to the market just to test that out.)  Otherwise, does anyone know if there's an API I can avoid calling that will make it so my app doesn't need this permission?

Thanks!

Answer (score 90, accepted):

(Answering my own question in case anyone else runs into this problem and searches for it.)

Digging around in PackageParser.java in the android source, I found out that the system will automatically assign

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and 
android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
```

to any app that declares a targetSdk version of less than 4 (donut).  There must be a compatibility reason for this, maybe apps targeting older versions could assume they had these permissions without declaring them explicitly.  So, if you don't want these permissions added to your app implicitly, add a section like the following in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
```

That is all.

Have fun, -Mike

Comment: So in 1.5 and prior you're saying these permissions are assigned by default and there's no recourse for mitigating that?

Comment: That's what it looks like to me.  Otherwise, I don't know why they'd be granted implicitly like that.  I suppose for a test, we could try running a 1.5 app on the 1.5 emulator/device, not setting any uses-permission and seeing if it's possible to (e.g.) write to the sdcard.  (That does work on the 1.6 emulator/device but only because of the implicitly added permissions.  Setting targetSdkVersion to 4 will force you to also add the uses-permission before writing to the sdcard.)

Comment: My `android:minSdkVersion` is 14 but `READ_PHONE_STATE` is granted implicitly. I am using Facebook SDK and GoogleMaps v2, is it possible that these libraries are responsible for the implicit permission request?

Answer (score 24):

Android 1.6 changelog: http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-1.6.html#api

> **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**: Allows an
>   application to write to external
>   storage. ***Applications using API Level
>   3 and lower will be implicitly granted
>   this permission (and this will be
>   visible to the user)***; Applications
>   using API Level 4 or higher must
>   explicitly request this permission.

But that is only one of them.  For some reason the official change log is missing the info about READ_PHONE_STATE.  The full story is cleared up here: http://blogs.zdnet.com/Burnette/?p=1369&page=3

> New permissions. 1.6 programs must
>   explicitly request the
>   **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission to
>   be able to modify the contents of the
>   SD card, and they must explicitly
>   request the **READ_PHONE_STATE**
>   permission to be able to be able to
>   retrieve phone state info. ***Apps
>   targeting earlier versions will always
>   request these permissions implicitly.***

So as you can see, there is no way to publish an app targeted at 1.5 or earlier without requesting those permissions when installed on phones running 1.6 or higher.