# Are there default permissions granted for applications on Android?

Tags: android, permissions

I have noticed in an application I wrote, in-spite of me not specifying any permission in the manifest file, the application throws up permissions granted, such as

> android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
>   android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

What is all that about? I was not even aware my application needs to write into external store, and I am pretty sure it doesn't need to. So why are these permission being granted when I never requested for them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thoose two were default in earlier API versions. Read more about it: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747178/android-permissions-phone-calls-read-phone-state-and-identity).