# Why implicit adding permissions

Tags: android

Installing a simple HelloWorld asks for permission to write to external storage, why? I have not added any request in my manifest? Looking in the logs I see "I/PackageParser(15463): Implicit adding android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to old pkg". I am compiling for Android 1.6 and installing on an Sony Ericsson X10. How do I avoid the request since my HelloWorld does not need any of those permissions and any user might be scared away due to shady permissions?

Comment: How are you doing it? Nothing should be asking for the permission, are you using something other than a textview?

Comment: Nope, nothing fancy. Only a simple TextView.

Answer (score 0):

> Installing a simple HelloWorld asks for permission to write to external storage, why?

Because either you do not have a `<uses-sdk>` element in your manifest or its `android:minSdkVersion` is set to `3` or lower. See [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747178/android-permissions-phone-calls-read-phone-state-and-identity) for more.

Comment: Thanks, but neither of them helps. I did have minSdkVersion set to 3 but changing it to 4 does not help. (I have verified that I got the new apk after installing).

Comment: Also, this seems to be X10 specific. Installing the same apk-file on the other android device I got, do not require those permissions.