# Android asking for unneeded permissions

Tags: android, permissions, widget

I have an Android widget that needs internet access, fine and coarse permissions only. However, when I install the apk file, it says it also needs access to read the phone state and identity, and access to storage. It doesn't need access to either, and the only permissions that are in the mainfest are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android permissions: Phone Calls: read phone state and identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747178/android-permissions-phone-calls-read-phone-state-and-identity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use minsdkversion as 4 or above this issue will disappear.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
```

Check this link [Android permissions: Phone Calls: read phone state and identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747178/android-permissions-phone-calls-read-phone-state-and-identity)

Comment: I am assuming the 2 permissions are required for Android 1.5 and lower then? My widget does not require those permissions, but is very simple and will work on lower versions, but I suppose that version 1.6 is really the lowest aceptable version at this point.