# Android CALL_PHONE permission issue

Tags: android, permissions

My App is not using the CALL_PHONE permission neither I've declared it in the manifest, but while installing the app, it shows that app is using CALL_PHONE permission. Please help me about this. I am developing for Android 1.6 and have installed the app for testing from SDCard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use minsdkversion as 4 or above this issue will disappear.

Check this link [Android permissions: Phone Calls: read phone state and identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747178/android-permissions-phone-calls-read-phone-state-and-identity)