# Android application incompatible with many phones

Tags: android, google-play

I wrote an application for Android and now one of the users reports that the application is incompatible with many phones. I think the requirements/permissions are not that exotic.
My manifest file has following code:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Incompatible phones are shown in gray:
[Market http://www.preston.be/market.png](http://www.preston.be/market.png)
Anyone an idea what's missing/wrong?

Comment: Why do you have internet permission twice. Jw, do you have specific resources for each screen size? You're also targeting for android versions that have about 4% of the market (1.5 and 1.6)

Comment: Do you have any `<uses-feature>` or `<uses-configuration>` elements in your manifest?

Comment: More specifically, you can use `aapt dump badging` to help diagnose this sort of problem: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#testing

Answer (score 2):

according to

```
android:minSdkVersion="3" android:maxSdkVersion="4"
```

you are supporting only devices with Android 1.5 and 1.6 
most of the devices have a newer OS version like froyo 2.2

install the latest SDK then in your android proyect go to "Properties" -> "Android"  and change the "Project Build Target", for example Android 2.2 , API level 8.

then change in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:minSdkVersion="3" android:maxSdkVersion="8"
```

then your app will be able to support more devices...

Comment: `android:targetSdkVersion` is not `android:maxSdkVersion`. The target does not specify an upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

Here lies the problem `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4"/>`.

You are targeting Android 1.6 handsets, there are less than 15 % handsets out there that have that version of Android. You should target the latest Android versions. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) is Android docs about api levels that will make this more useful for you.

Also read up what it says about versions [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

As @commonsware mentioned below, I misunderstood, this. My apologies.

Comment: `android:targetSdkVersion` is not `android:maxSdkVersion`. The target does not specify an upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with the SDK versions you're using, there's an implied CALL_PHONE permission (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655266/android-call-phone-permission-issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116768/application-does-not-show-up-in-android-market-for-motorola-xoom-tablet) for more detailed explanations).  You should be able to work around this by changing the targetSdkVersion as shown in the second link.