# How to delete unnecessary permissions in Android?

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

Some additional permissions, not coded in Manifest, show up while installing my application on a real device, e.g. I have coded:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

While installing I see also Storage(Modify/delete USB storage contents) and Phone Calls(Read phone status and ID) permissions.

(Activities don't use any additional permissions.)

I would like to know, how can they be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android 1.6 changelog: http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-1.6.html#api

> **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**: Allows an
>   application to write to external
>   storage. ***Applications using API Level
>   3 and lower will be implicitly granted
>   this permission (and this will be
>   visible to the user)***; Applications
>   using API Level 4 or higher must
>   explicitly request this permission.

But that is only one of them.  For some reason the official change log is missing the info about READ_PHONE_STATE.  The full story is cleared up here: http://blogs.zdnet.com/Burnette/?p=1369&page=3

> New permissions. 1.6 programs must
>   explicitly request the
>   **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permission to
>   be able to modify the contents of the
>   SD card, and they must explicitly
>   request the **READ_PHONE_STATE**
>   permission to be able to be able to
>   retrieve phone state info. ***Apps
>   targeting earlier versions will always
>   request these permissions implicitly.***

So as you can see, there is no way to publish an app targeted at 1.5 or earlier without requesting those permissions when installed on phones running 1.6 or higher.

Quoting from [Android permissions: Phone Calls: read phone state and identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747178/android-permissions-phone-calls-read-phone-state-and-identity/1977832#1977832)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I really use min SDK version = 3. That's the exact reason.

Comment: Now I set minSdkVersion to 4 and these permissions disappeared.