# which one of these permissions in manifest says I'm reading phone call information?

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

I have a few permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

When I go to install my application, it says it has access to: "Phone calls - read phone state and identity."  Which of these permissions is triggering that warning?  I never read phone call information.  Is it my use of PowerManager.isScreenOn() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with a bug where you need to at least specify a minimum SDK of 4:

[Android permissions: Phone Calls: read phone state and identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747178/android-permissions-phone-calls-read-phone-state-and-identity)

Answer (score 1):

By a process of elimination, I would suggest it was: `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` as none of the others are specifically to do with the phone.

Comment: that's kind of lame.  It seems to overscare the user, but all I'm doing is accessing WifiManager.  That has nothing to do with phone calls.

Comment: eek, it turned out to be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747178/android-permissions-phone-calls-read-phone-state-and-identity

Comment: Ouch. Is it all fixed for you now?

Answer (score 0):

none of these are  related to read phone call info. As it should be like .READ_PHONE_STATE(read phone call). I think it must  be because of ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.