# React-Native unnecessary Android user permissions automatically added on build?

Tags: android, react-native

It seems like Read/Write external storage and Read phone state permissions are automatically added to the manifest on building the android apk. Are these necessary for all React Native android apps? Is there any way to remove these permissions?

Looking at the **build/output/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt** I see:

```
android:uses-permission#android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
IMPLIED from `/***/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:1:1-22:12 reason: org.webkit.android_jsc` requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

It feels weird that I'll see these permissions being requested if I install the app from the Play store if I'm not using them.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Here is my AndroidManifest.xml https://gist.github.com/1985media/385f726cf4f035ec3ed1

Comment: This seems related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747178/android-permissions-phone-calls-read-phone-state-and-identity. However, simply adding this to my own manifest isn't sufficient: android/app/build/outputs/logs/manifest-merger-debug-report.txt suggests the permission is added because org.webkit.android_jsc has targetSdkVersion < 4. Not sure yet how to get rid of that.

Comment: Did we ever come to a solution on this? I am still getting extra permissions being added to my react native app.

Answer (score 21):

I have an answer.

AndroidManifest.xml

Add this to manifest which should be line 1

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

It should look like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      package="YOUR PACKAGE NAME">
```

Now you can remove the permissions with this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
```

So my permissions for a simple app are

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
```

Don't remove SYSTEM.ALERT.WINDOW, you will have problems in development.

Comment: Also don't remove internet permissions for running in debug mode. it needs them to contact the packager.

Comment: SYSTEM.ALERT.WINDOW I have remove it from production build how I do that