# Permissions added to manifest during build

Tags: android, react-native, camera

This is React Native app which is kinda out of date.

Got a weird (at least to me) issue.

In our AndroidManifest.xml file we explicitly **don't** request Camera permission because the library we use, `react-native-image-picker`, says we don't need to. Well, the build seems to add the permission to the manifest file.

I'm trying to figure out how during the build it's getting inserted into the manifest.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.tego">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!-- If "android.permission.CAMERA" is added, explicit request is required for react-native-image-picker -->
```

AndroidManifest.xml in the build folder

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" /> <!-- If "android.permission.CAMERA" is added, explicit request is required for react-native-image-picker -->
.
.
.

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" /> <!-- Required by older versions of Google Play services to create IID tokens -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33728382/react-native-unnecessary-android-user-permissions-automatically-added-on-build)

Add
`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

and then in my case added this to the manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" tools:node="remove" />`